# Как забрать значение InLine кнопки и чтобы записать в FSM

Tags: python, бот, aiogram

```
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram import types, Dispatcher
from TelegramBot.create_bot import bot
from TelegramBot.sqlRequests import SqlRequests as mSql
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton


class FSMSearchArticle(StatesGroup):
    searchArticle = State()
    brandID = State()


# @dp.message_handler(commands=['search_article'], state=None)
async def start_search_article(message: types.Message):
    await FSMSearchArticle.searchArticle.set()
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, " Введите номер запчасти")
    await message.delete()


# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMSearchArticle.searchArticle)
async def load_search_article(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['s_article'] = message.text
        nor = mSql.number_of_results(message.text)
        article_result = mSql.search_by_article(message.text)
        if nor == 0:
            await state.finish()
            await message.reply(" ❌ Жаль, но я не знаю номер: " + message.text + "\n\n")
        elif nor == 1:
            await state.finish()
            result = ('\nАртикул:  ' + str(article_result[0][1]) + '\n'
                      + 'Бренд:  ' + str(article_result[0][3]) + '\n'
                      + 'Наименование:  ' + str(article_result[0][4]))
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)
        else:
            brand_inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            for i in article_result:
                brand_inline_keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[3], callback_data=i[2]))
            await FSMSearchArticle.next()
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Данный артикул присутствует в нескольких брендах!\n\n"
                                                         " Пожалуйста выберете необходимый бренд.",
                                   reply_markup=brand_inline_keyboard)


# @dp.callback_query_handler(text="text")
async def load_brand(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["brand_id"] = callback_query.data

        print(data)

        await bot.send_message('результат !!!!! ДОПИСАТЬ')
        await state.finish()


def register_handlers_client_search_article(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(start_search_article, commands=['search_article'])
    dp.register_message_handler(load_search_article, state=FSMSearchArticle.searchArticle)
    dp.register_message_handler(load_brand, text="text")
```

Не понимаю как написать следующий handler, чтобы callback_data была записана в FSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не давайте такой обрезанный код пожалуйста, если вы присылаете хендлер то пришлите его начиная с декоратора.
А насчет вопроса, то это делается вот так.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="text")
async def echos(callback_query: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["data_callback"] = callback_query.data
```

UPD1. Ааа, ты так занимаешься этими извращениями с регистрацией хендлеров? Тогда понятно.
Ну смотри, меняй вот это
`dp.register_message_handler(load_brand, text="text")` на вот это  `dp.register_callback_handler(load_brand, text="text")`.
А ещё лучше будет полный отказ от регистрации хедлеров таким способом. Просто сделай пакет с инитом, который импортирует разбитые по папкам модули с хендлерами внутри и вот этот пакет импортируй в основном файле. В PyCharm'е он будет выделяться серым так как не используется, но он свою задачу сделал, он зарегистрировал их и они будут работать, главное не забывать импортировать новые модули в ините.
UPD2. Ну так само собой он не будет срабатывать ведь в `@dp.callback_query_handler(text="text")` нужно заменить "text" на ту колбек дату которую возвращает тебе инлайн кнопка. К примеру можно вот так.

```
# @dp.message_handler(state=FSMSearchArticle.searchArticle)
async def load_search_article(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['s_article'] = message.text
        nor = mSql.number_of_results(message.text)
        article_result = mSql.search_by_article(message.text)
        if nor == 0:
            await state.finish()
            await message.reply(" ❌ Жаль, но я не знаю номер: " + message.text + "\n\n")
        elif nor == 1:
            await state.finish()
            result = ('\nАртикул:  ' + str(article_result[0][1]) + '\n'
                      + 'Бренд:  ' + str(article_result[0][3]) + '\n'
                      + 'Наименование:  ' + str(article_result[0][4]))
            await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)
        else:
            brand_inline_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            for i in article_result:
                brand_inline_keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[3], callback_data=f"load_search:{i[2]}"))
            await FSMSearchArticle.next()
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Данный артикул присутствует в нескольких брендах!\n\n"
                                                         " Пожалуйста выберете необходимый бренд.",
                                   reply_markup=brand_inline_keyboard)


# @dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="load_search:")
async def load_brand(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data["brand_id"] = callback_query.data.split(":")[1]

        print(data)

        await bot.send_message('результат !!!!! ДОПИСАТЬ')
        await state.finish()
```

Comment: Не получается, обновил свой вопрос и выложил весь код.

Comment: Тоже обновил___

Comment: Спасибо что уделяете мне время. Я изменил на dp.register_callback_handler(load_brand, text="text"), но кнопку так и не считывает. Он даже не заходит в этот хэндлер. У меня на входе стоит print для консоли, так он не срабатывает.

Comment: И еще раз, проверяй

Comment: Я в шоке, всё сделал, как вы написали, перепроверил каждую буковку, а оно всё равно не работает. Крутятся часики после нажатия на in-line  кнопку и не заходит в  dp.register_callback_handler …. Я вообще холодный …

Comment: А вы меняли то что было на вот это, а  text_startswith="load_search:" ??

Comment: И вот эта строка тоже важна                 brand_inline_keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[3], callback_data=f"load_search:{i[2]}"))

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо. Я не попадал в callback_query_handler потому что при регистрации забыл написать register ... ))))

Огромнейшее ВАМ спасибо!

Comment: Тогда закрывай вопрос, нажав на галочку слева от ответа

Comment: А можно ещё один вопрос? Я ведь открыл FSM. А как её закрыть, если пользователь не нажал на inline кнопку, а ввёл какой-то текст или отправил другую команду ... ?

Comment: Где именно вы его открыли? И что значит отрыли? Сделали .set() ?

Comment: Это в этом же коде. Открыл я его в @dp.message_handler(commands=['search_article'], state=None). А в @dp.message_handler(state=FSMSearchArticle.searchArticle) я его либо закрываю, либо отправляю дальше в @dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="brand_id:"). Так вот если пользователь вместо inline кнопки напишет просто сообщение или же отправит команду, как сказать ему, чтобы нажал на кнопку inline, либо же закрыть FSM и сказать пользователю, что нужно было нажать, а так пусть начинает с начала....

Comment: Сделай колбек хендлер с фильтром стейта, который используется, и в нем сделай сенж месседж того что хочешь сказать юзеру.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я что-то не понял как сделать этот callback handler с фильтром state. В любом случаи благодарю Вас за уделённое мне время, буду дальше ковырять.

Comment: @dp.callback_query_handler(state=FSMSearchArticle) async def namefunca(call: types.CallbackQuery):...